# Git branches not merged after switching from svn

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-merge, subgit

I used [subgit](http://subgit.com/) to transform an old svn repository to git (including full history, branches, tags). After some initial trouble I got it working and it worked almost perfectly. Except branches doesn't seem to be merged back to the trunk/master branch:

[image]

As you can see, git knows that I branched the green master to get the black branch. But it doesn't seem to know that this branch was merged back to the master at commit `73653d1`. It just looks like I abandoned that branch and independently implemented all that in one single commit in the master branch.

This isn't how a correct merge is supposed to look like, right? Is there a way to fix this? Note that this is about 50 commits back in history and besides the seemingly missing reference, the code is fine.

Comment: Missing merge commit basically means that trunk didn't get proper _svn:mergeinfo_ property after `svn merge`. Could you please run `svn propget svn:mergeinfo ^/trunk@rXYZ` where `rXYZ` is the revision of `73653d1`. Does mergeinfo include revisions r141:148 of the branch?

Comment: `svn:mergeinfo ^/trunk@r149` returns `/branches/restructure:142-148`

Comment: @vadishev Does this mean it was merged correctly with svn? Maybe the merge information got only lost during the switch to git.

Comment: BTW, did you delete ^/branches/restructure? Otherwise refs/heads/restructure should still be there in Git repository. If you've deleted the branch, you still can reach it from git by running `git fetch origin refs/svn/attic/branches/restructure/*:refs/tmp/restructure/*` it should fetch those revisions when the branch existed before its deletion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So,

r141: copied ^/trunk to ^/branches/restructure
r142: modified ^/branches/restructure
...
r148: modified ^/branches/restructure
r149: merged r142:148 from ^/branches/restructure to ^/trunk

That is, one didn't merge r141 of ^/branches/restructure into ^/trunk at r149.

As you probably know, merge commit in Git includes the whole history of every its parent. That's why SubGit checks whether all the necessary revisions were merged into a corresponding branch when it creates a merge commit.

In your case SubGit detected r141 as a gap in the history of ^/branches/restructure, that's why it didn't add this branch as a merge parent to commit `73653d1`.

One may argue:

> r141 didn't introduce any file or directory modifications, so why SubGit needs including this revision into svn:mergeinfo?

Well, in common case, a single SVN revision may create a branch *and* modify any file in it. That's why SubGit still checks every revision in history of the branch.

However, SubGit may be a bit smarter and check whether revision that creates a branch modifies any file in it, so for your case SubGit would create a merge commit automatically. We may implement that in future; here's [the issue](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-556) for that at our tracker.

How to fix the history in Git?

As Subversion doesn't allow any modifications in existing history, you have to create a new revision which adds missing r141 into svn:mergeinfo property of ^/trunk. Consider do the following for that:

```
$ svn switch ^/trunk .
$ svn merge --record-only ^/branches/restructure@148 .
$ svn commit -m 'Merged r141 of restructure changes into the trunk'
```

If you keep Subversion and Git repositories synchronized, SubGit should automatically translate this revision into merge commit. Otherwise you can translate the history from scratch or just install SubGit once again into the same SVN repository.

UPDATE:
How to fix history in Git repository if you don't need SVN sync anymore?

You can rewrite the part of Git history starting from `73653d1` commit with the following command:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter \
'test $GIT_COMMIT = 73653d1 && echo "-p 2ec9e8c -p 5c237f9" || cat' master
```

NB: Put full commit IDs instead of abbreviated `73653d1`, `2ec9e8c` and `5c237f9`.

This command should add `5c237f9` commit as a merge parent to `73653d1` commit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried this, but it makes it look like I just merged that branch to my trunk now, even though I (incorrectly) merged it a lot of revisions back. Would it be possible to fix the history in git? I'm not synching back to svn and I'm to only user of this repo.

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite part of the history in order to add a merge parent to `73653d1` commit. I've just updated my answer on that.

Comment: Thank you so much! After changing the parents, a part of the history got repeated in an other branch that based on master, but I was able to rebase it and I think everything is right now. I just realized you are actually one of the subgit developers, so thanks a lot for that too! Maybe you should setup a donate button for people who use the free or open source license.

Comment: My pleasure. The feedback like yours is very valuable for us, it's a great way to donate to our project. So, if you have any issues with SubGit — tell us, if SubGit just works and does it well — tell everyone in the world :)